# postgresql start problems on odoo

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm, odoo

I tried to configure pycharm for odoo project and had this problem "psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied" They said that I have to edit the pg_hba.conf to put the line
"local all all trust". After I edit the file, My next problem is that I could not restart my PostgreSQL service.

Thank you. Btw, I have python 3.8 and odoo 13 with the latest version of pycharm.

Comment: Mention your operating system and version. You need to see your PostgreSQL log file to troubleshoot. In Ubuntu, that may be in /var/log/postgresql/.

Comment: windows 10 and the latest version.